# Accordion/collapsible

Tags: javascript, html

The code I wrote to do this effect stays "fixed" on top or on bottom.  I did it the manual hard-coded way and wanted some advice on the best way to write something like this.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Le7qqv/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
if (id == 'firstDivHeader')
{

document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '82px';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '41px';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '0px';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



} else if (id == 'secondDivHeader')
{

document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '41px';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '41px';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '0px';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



} else if (id == 'thirdDivHeader')
{


document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '41px';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '82px';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '0';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '0px';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



} else if (id == 'forthDivHeader')
{

document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '41px';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '82px';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '123px';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



}
}

</script>
<div id=menuContainer>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('firstDivHeader');"> <div id="firstDivHeader" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #560000; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    First Div
</div>
    </a>
    <div class=item id="firstDivResults" style="display: none;">
blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
        blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />

    </div>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('secondDivHeader');"> <div id="secondDivHeader" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #560000; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    Second Div
</div>
    </a>
        <div class=item id="secondDivResults" style="display: none;">
        blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
        blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />

    </div>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('thirdDivHeader');"> <div id="thirdDivHeader" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #560000; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    third Div
</div>
    </a>
        <div class=item id="thirdDivResults" style="display: none;">blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
        blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />

    </div>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('forthDivHeader');"> <div id="forthDivHeader" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #560000; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    Fourth Div
</div>
    </a>

<div class=item id="forthDivResults" style="display: none;">
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />
       blah<br />
    blah<br />
    blah<br />

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Couldn't you come up with better content than repeated `blah` separated by line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Helper Functions

You can make the code shorter with a helper function.  Replace code like

> ```
> document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '';
> document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '82px';
> document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';
> ```

with

```
            set_position('secondDivHeader', '', '82px');
```

Which is defined as

```
  function set_position(id, top, bottom) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = top;
    document.getElementById(id).style.bottom = bottom;
    document.getElementById(id).style.position = 'fixed';
  }
```

### Naming

You misspelled `fourth`.

Names like `fourthDiv` are brittle and difficult to maintain.  It's better to make the names reflect the actual content.  That's somewhat hampered here by the lack of actual content.

### `toggle_visibility`

> ```
> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('firstDivHeader');"> <div id="firstDivHeader" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: #560000; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
> ```

If you change this code to

```
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('firstDivResults');"> <div id="firstDivHeader">
```

Then you can just say

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
```

to display a section.  Also, you should define your CSS in a `<style>` block (or external file), not inline.

```
<style>
#firstDivHeader, #secondDivHeader, #thirdDivHeader, #fourthDivHeader {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #560000;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

You could simplify that by declaring a CSS class that covered those four cases.  Or possibly a different element, e.g. an `<h2>`.

### Hiding

> ```
> document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
> ```

Every occurrence like this can be replaced by a single `hide_all` function:

```
function hide_all() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

> ```
>     <div class=item id="firstDivResults" style="display: none;">
> ```

Rather than hide it in the HTML, hide in JavaScript:

```
    hide_all();
```

This will also allow people who don't have JavaScript to view the content.

### `switch`

> ```
> if (id == 'firstDivHeader')
> } else if (id == 'secondDivHeader')
> } else if (id == 'thirdDivHeader')
> } else if (id == 'forthDivHeader')
> ```

This form of `if`/`else` is often better done with a `switch` statement.

```
        switch (id) {
          case 'firstDivResults':
            break;
          case 'secondDivResults':
            break;
          case 'thirdDivResults':
            break;
          case 'fourthDivResults':
            break;
        }
```

The `switch` makes it clearer that all the cases are based on the value of `id`.  An `if`/`else` is more flexible.

### Final Version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
    #firstDivHeader, #secondDivHeader, #thirdDivHeader, #fourthDivHeader {
        z-index: 100;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #560000;
        border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id=menuContainer>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('firstDivResults');"> <div id="firstDivHeader">
        First Div
    </div>
        </a>
        <div class="item" id="firstDivResults">
    blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
            blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />

        </div>


    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('secondDivResults');"> <div id="secondDivHeader">
        Second Div
    </div>
        </a>
            <div class="item" id="secondDivResults">
            blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
            blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />

        </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('thirdDivResults');"> <div id="thirdDivHeader">
        Third Div
    </div>
        </a>
            <div class="item" id="thirdDivResults">blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
            blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />

        </div>


    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('fourthDivResults');"> <div id="fourthDivHeader">
        Fourth Div
    </div>
        </a>

    <div class="item" id="fourthDivResults">
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />
           blah<br />
        blah<br />
        blah<br />

        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function hide_all() {
          var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
          for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
            elements[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
      }

      function set_position(id, top, bottom) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.top = top;
        document.getElementById(id).style.bottom = bottom;
        document.getElementById(id).style.position = 'fixed';
      }

      function toggle_visibility(id) {
        hide_all();

        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
        document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

        switch (id) {
          case 'firstDivResults':
            set_position('secondDivHeader', '', '82px');
            set_position('thirdDivHeader', '', '41px');
            set_position('fourthDivHeader', '', '0px');
            break;
          case 'secondDivResults':
            set_position('secondDivHeader', '41px', '');
            set_position('thirdDivHeader', '', '41px');
            set_position('fourthDivHeader', '', '0px');
            break;
          case 'thirdDivResults':
            set_position('secondDivHeader', '41px', '');
            set_position('thirdDivHeader', '81px', '');
            set_position('fourthDivHeader', '', '0px');
            break;
          case 'fourthDivResults':
            set_position('secondDivHeader', '41px', '');
            set_position('thirdDivHeader', '81px', '');
            set_position('fourthDivHeader', '121px', '');
            break;
        }
      }

    hide_all();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very very very nice explanation on things that all helped me tremendously understand a lot about java script formatting and gives me great ideas moving forward.  I extremely appreciate your help